# How to disable a button if no checked boxes are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have checkbox column in my data table and I want to hide a button if none of checked boxes clicked.[including pagination].
below is my code I used to get the values when clicking button,pls advice,

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var id = "";
    var oTable = $("#userTable").dataTable();
    $(".groupCheckBox:checked", oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function () {
        if (id != "") {
            id = id + "," + $(this).val();
        } else {
            id = $(this).val();
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event listener to all of your checkboxes. Whenever something changes, you check if all of them are un-checked => disable the button, else => enable the button.

```
$(".groupCheckBox").on('change', function(){
    if($(".groupCheckBox:checked", oTable.fnGetNodes()).length == 0){
        $('#merge_button').prop('disabled', true);
    }else{
        $('#merge_button').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: when user checked 3 boxes and unchecked one box again button get hidden . how to fix it.

Comment: Or just `$('#merge_button').prop('disabled', $(".groupCheckBox:checked").length == 0)`

Comment: You mean disabled? Have all your checkboxes the class "groupCheckBox"? I'm not entirely sure if the jQuery selector works with class:checked. I would use input[name=name_of_the_boxes]:checked instead of .groupCheckBox:checked.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that actually looks pretty nice :) It's a bit harder to read though, so I'll let the answer the way it is.

Comment: @user2415266 : this doesn't work with data table pagination. when I checked a box in 2nd page of pagination, still the button disable . pls advice

Comment: Well...it will obviously take the current status of the checkboxes. If you are using pagination: where do you store the data if a checkbox is checked on a previous page? Then you still use the event listener, but you have to check the place where you store all the checked/not-checked values to see if any is checked or not.

Comment: @user2415266 : how to store values of previous pages ? pls advice kindly

Comment: Ohh...I think that's why you used `oTable.fnGetNodes()` before in your original function. I've added that to my answer as well - try if it works now. I have some experience with DataTables, but haven't used `oTable.fnGetNodes()` before. Guessing it will give you all nodes, not just the ones displayed on the page.

Comment: @user2415266 : can u please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027958/combined-2-arrays-in-select-box-jquery-chosen-js

Answer (score 0):

`$('#merge_button')` disabled by default and a `change` event listener to all `$('.groupCheckBox')` elements.. In the event handler check if any checkbox is checked to update the button property:

```js
$('.groupCheckBox').on('change', function() {
  $('#merge_button').prop('disabled', $('input.groupCheckBox:checkbox:checked').length === 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="groupCheckBox">
<input type="checkbox" class="groupCheckBox">
<input type="checkbox" class="groupCheckBox">
<input type="checkbox" class="groupCheckBox">
<input type="checkbox" class="groupCheckBox">
<input type="checkbox" class="groupCheckBox">
<input type="checkbox" class="groupCheckBox">
<input type="checkbox" class="groupCheckBox">

<hr>

<button id="merge_button" disabled>Merge</button>
```